# JQuery Resizable demo site

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and I am trying to implement JQueryUI resizable into my code. But it's not quite easy for me to implement using example given in [demo site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#default).

Can some one please provide some other example sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is have the following ...

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.load("jquery",'1.7.1');</script>
<script>google.load("jqueryui", "1");</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />​
```

1. google script just prepares googles cdn
2. google.load()// it loads jquery and jquery ui (javascript only)
3. You need the jqui css

http://jsfiddle.net/cKsj3/

Explaination:

The above are CDN meaning hosted on google or microsoft so I dont have to, to show to you.
but on jquery UI you need to download a theme there.

and pick up the following files

```
jquery core js
jquery ui js
jquery ui css
jquery images provided...
```

so you put them on your host e.g. public_html.

then you link them as above but change the src and href where applicable.

Comment: Thanks Val.. I got it. Can I know, do I have to have use their UI stylesheet?

Comment: well yes and no... is the right answer, yes you do coz you need to show the icon on the bottom right corner, no, coz you can re-style it yourself :) otherwise your script may have work all this time it's that your icon was not visible and you didnt know where to drag :) look into firebug (google it) it will help you alot.